# mongodb update data type of a field from map to array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

how can we update the data type of a field in a document from map to an array.
Suppose for following document:

```
{
    "_id" : "someUniqueId:1234567890",
    "field1" : {
        "id" : "field1_id1",
        "type" : "field1_type1"
    },
    "field2" : "field2_value",
    "field3" : 1680
}
```

I want to update the field1 to have value:

```
"field1" : [{
        "id" : "field1_id1",
        "type" : "field1_type1"
    }]
```

I have tried following:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').find({_id: "someUniqueId:1234567890"}).forEach(function(result) {
        db.getCollection('collection1').update({_id: result._id}, { $insert: { field1: [{"field1.id": result.field1.id, "field1.type": result.field1.type}] } })
});
```

also, I have tried $push and $addToSet in place of $insert, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) to get the result

The Below query does the change

```
db.collection_name.update(
  {},
  [{ $set: { field1: ["$field1"] } }],
  { multi: true }
);
```

Find Part - `{}`

We have not given any condition here to pick the specific documents for update, hence the update is for all documents in the collection, if we want to restrict the update - please provide the condition to pick the matching documents

Update Part - `[{ $set: { field1: ["$field1"] } }]`

Does the job of making the document into array

```
multi:true
```

Flag is set to true so that we can update multiple documents

Please note - Run the query only once into your collection, if we run it multiple times then we will be having nested array for field1

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: In order to avoid nested arrays, you should add condition `{ field1: { $not: { $type: "array" } } }` instead of `{}`

Comment: Condition `{ "field1.0": { $exists: false } } ` works also but `{ field1: { $type: "obejct" } }` **does not** work.